# Prop 3.20 of Lee's smooth manifolds. If $M$ is a smooth n-manifold covered by a single smooth chart, $TM$ is diffeomorphic to $M \times \Bbb R^n.$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

About the following Proposition 3.20 of Introduction to smooth manifolds by Lee

[image]

As a reference also see

[image]
[image]

**Why can I just declare that $\tilde \varphi $ is a diffeomorphism as stated at the end and not prove it?**
All I know is that $\tilde \varphi $is a bijection from the proof of proposition 3.18 and that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, but it is not clear to me how to show that $\tilde \varphi $ is a diffeomorphism. I would to prove smoothness by writing the coordinate representation I guess
**Can this be deduced from (3.13)?**

Comment: You cannot. You have to verify the diffeomorphism property either by an explicit calculation or by using the inverse mapping theorem. The author expects you to be able to do so.

Comment: @MoisheKohan. What do you mean with the diffeomorphism property?.  In this case it looks like the atlas has a single chart, which is the global one, isn't it? Then the smoothness is automatic, because any transition map is just the identity

Comment: I was talking about the proof of Proposition 3.18 in the image from Lee's book that you posted. I thought, you are asking about that. The claim in Proposition 3.20 is trivially true.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you explain why is it trivially true?. I doubt my statement that the global atlas is the only atlas is true. After all restricting to any open set would create another chart and that has to be in the maximal atlas too.

Comment: Do you know why the tangent bundle of $R^n$ is trivial?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are confused by the statement

> the smooth structure on $TM$ is defined essentially by declaring $\tilde \varphi $ to be a diffeomorphism.

This is perhaps a bit sloppy, but what Lee means becomes clear in Proposition 3.18.

Given a manifold $M$, the tangent bundle $TM$ is defined as the disjoint union of the tangent spaces at all points of $M$. This is a just a set, it does not yet have a topology and a smooth structure. Topology and smooth structure are **defined** in Proposition 3.18.

For all smooth charts $(\varphi,U)$ on $M$ one defines a bijection
$$\tilde \varphi : \pi^{-1}(U) \to \varphi(U) \times \mathbb R^n$$
whose codomain is an open subset of $\mathbb R^{2n}$. Then it is proved (using Lemma 1.35) that there exists a unique topology and smooth structure on $TM$ such that the $(\tilde \varphi ,\pi^{-1}(U))$ become smooth charts. This means that they are diffeomorphisms between the smooth manifolds $\pi^{-1}(U)$ and $\varphi(U) \times \mathbb R^n$.

Is $M$ is covered by a singles smooth chart $(\varphi,M)$, then we get a diffeomorphism
$$\tilde \varphi : TM = \pi^{-1}(M) \to \varphi(M) \times \mathbb R^n .$$
This means that
$$\hat \varphi : TM \xrightarrow{\tilde \varphi} \varphi(M) \times \mathbb R^n \xrightarrow{\varphi^{-1} \times id} M \times \mathbb R^n$$
is the desired diffeomorphism.